# External button triggering Update Panel with Repeater?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, repeater

I have a page on which Account Numbers are fetched dynamically on Page Load and shown in buttons. Now on particular account number click, I want that account number complete transactions to be shown just below the buttons without page load.

My aspx code is

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <%if(AccountNumbers.Count() > 0) { %>

        <div class="account-message">
            <p>You have following account(s). Please click to get complete transaction details :</p>
        </div>

        <div class="account-number-container">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                <%
                    int count = AccountNumbers.Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
                %>
                        <li><button class="btn btn-primary" id="<%= AccountNumbers[i] %>" type="button"><%= AccountNumbers[i] %></button></li>
                <%
                    }
                %>

                <li><button class="btn btn-primary" id="<%= Session["user_id"] %>" type="button">All</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <%} else { %>
        <div class="account-message">
            <p>Sorry, you have no accounts</p>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterGetTransactions" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSourceGetTransactions">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="showTransactions" class="cell-border hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Transaction Id</th>
                                <th>Loan Amount</th>
                                <th>Installment</th>
                                <th>Transaction Date</th>
                                <th>Balance</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionId")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LoanAmount")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Amount")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionDate")%>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Balance")%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>

                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSourceGetTransactions" runat="server"
        SelectMethod="GetTransaction"
        TypeName="AutoIdentificationProcess.Presenters.TransactionPresenter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

The Update Panel should show transactions of the recent button clicked. Now how to do that  using Update Panel.

This is my code behind:

```
//Gets the number of accounts
     public List<string> GetNumberOfAccounts(string userId)
         {
             TransactionBAL TransactionBal = new TransactionBAL();
             return TransactionBal.GetNumberOfAccounts(userId);
        }
```

> ```
>     //This method gets the complete transaction details for a particular account
>     public TransactionsBO[] GetTransaction(string accountNumber)
>     {
>         TransactionBAL TransactionBal = new TransactionBAL();
>         return TransactionBal.GetTransaction(accountNumber);
>     }
> ```

Comment: anyone working on the code ??